# Keeping track of which view a partial is called from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I call the same partial from multiple views in Rails, the show page and the edit page. How can I keep track of which view the partial is called from? More specifically, I would like to adapt the partial slightly depending on which page it is rendered from. I have tried to request the uri using `url_for(:only_path => true)` and if-else statements to determine if the partial is rendered on the show or edit page, but this is a bit cumbersome. Is there a better approach?

Comment: you can try to use `current_page?` helper, i.e. `if current_page?(root_path)`

Comment: Thanks, what I needed, works great.. you can put it as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use `current_page?` helper, i.e. `if current_page?(root_path)`

Answer (score 1):

We put this in our application.html.erb template which shows the current controller, view and more debug information:

```
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

I think we got this from the Rails site:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html